# trying to add an element to xml using XSLT and give it a value

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml file that i want to add an element = carrier to and give it a value = ABF.  the original file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<ABF>
<QUOTEID>L9V5442611</QUOTEID>
<CHARGE>166.08</CHARGE> 
<ADVERTISEDTRANSIT>1 Day</ADVERTISEDTRANSIT>
```

i am using this xslt file below to make the following changes

1- add QUOTETENDER as the beginning and ending elements ..
2- remove ABF
3- insert a CARRIER element and give it the value of ABF

i was able to achieve 1 and 2 but can not get 3 done

the result i need is the xml snippet at the bottom

... can someone help ..thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/> 

    <xsl:template match="ABF">
        <xsl:element name="QUOTETENDER">
            <xsl:element name="CARRIER"></xsl:element>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<QUOTETENDER>
<CARRIER>ABF</CARRIER>
<QUOTEID>L9V5442611</QUOTEID>
<CHARGE>166.08</CHARGE>
<ADVERTISEDTRANSIT>1 Day</ADVERTISEDTRANSIT>
</QUOTETENDER>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add `ABF` inside of the CARRIER element:

```
<xsl:element name="CARRIER">ABF</xsl:element>
```

You could simplify things and use literal element declarations, since your element names are static and not dynamically determined:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/> 
    
    <xsl:template match="ABF">
        <QUOTETENDER>
            <CARRIER>ABF</CARRIER>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </QUOTETENDER>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You could also use the `local-name()` of the matched `ABF` element:

```
<CARRIER><xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/></CARRIER>
```